# why my html draggable is not working on touch screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created the draggable div in that i have added some headers and p tag but when i run that particular index page on touch screen , i am unable to drag the div tag , what is the best solution for this , i want to run this page on touch screen , will someone provide me the best solution for this ?

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
             <body>
            <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>
             <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV 
             element</p>

            <div id="mydiv">
            <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
            <p>Move</p>
            <p>this</p>
            <p>DIV</p>
            </div>

            <script>
            //Make the DIV element draggagle javscript code :
            dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

            function dragElement(elmnt) {
            var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
            if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header"))
            {
           /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
            document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = 
            dragMouseDown;
           } 
            else {
            /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
            elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
           }

          function dragMouseDown(e) {
           e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
          // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
           pos3 = e.clientX;
           pos4 = e.clientY;
           document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
           // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
           document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
          }

            function elementDrag(e) {
             e = e || window.event;
             e.preventDefault();
             // calculate the new cursor position:
             pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
             pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
             pos3 = e.clientX;
             pos4 = e.clientY;
             // set the element's new position:
            elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
            elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
           }

             function closeDragElement() {
              /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
             document.onmouseup = null;
             document.onmousemove = null;
             }
           }
          </script>

         </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events may be emulated on touch devices, but not always. You need to support [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events) along with mouse events.
Be carefull when browsers emulate mouse events to not trigger twice your events handlers.

Since you use JQuery, you may be interested by [Pointer Events Polyfill](https://github.com/jquery/PEP).

Comment: can you tell me how should i do with this code .. will you able to modify my above code so with the help of that i can generate more functionality .

Comment: If you want a better answer, please edit your question with an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve